# Installing web developer plugin for Firefox 3.6 from corp. network

Tags: installation, firefox-addon, web-developer-toolbar

I'm trying to install the web developer plugin, and it's failing with a message that "Web Developer 1.1.8 could not be installed because it is not compatible with Firefox 3.6.13".

I don't believe that it's actually incompatible; rather I think the problem is because the installation fails during a validation check, probably because the corp. network is messing with the connections.  The message I get is that:

services.addons.mozilla.org uses an invalid security certificate

and when I view the certificate, it's issued by the networking group, not mozilla.

Is there a way to by-pass the version check so I can install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the XPI you were trying to install had `em:maxVersion` in its install.rdf smaller than the Firefox version, so Firefox was checking with addons.mozilla.org to see if the version you were trying to install was marked as compatible (addons.mozilla.org allows to bump the maxVersion, but doesn't update the XPI it serves to the users).

If for any reason that update check failed, Firefox wouldn't let you install the extension.

The solution in that case (extension version actually compatible with Firefox, but has stale information in its install.rdf) would be to edit the XPI to bump maxVersion manually before attempting to install the XPI.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird that it's giving you the "not compatible with Firefox version x" message since, as you say, that doesn't seem to be the actual problem. See if this works: Right-click on the installer link and select "Save Link As..." and save the file on your hard drive. It will be called something like webdeveloper.xpi. Then just drag and drop the file onto Firefox.

Comment: It still didn't help.  However, about an hour after I posted this question, a new version 1.1.9 was posted, and that did install despite the cert problems, so that might have been an unrelated issue.